# How to Dynamically Increase the Height of a Widget in a Flutter Row Widget Based on Another Flexible Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a layout where there are two children in a `Row` widget, both of which are flexible widgets. The left side widget contains both red and blue colored widgets, and I want to increase the height of the blue color widget based on the height of the right side widget (which is a flexible widget with a flex value of 7).

**Ex1:** The height of the blue color widget to be dynamically adjusted based on the height of the right side widget (with a flex value of 7).

**Ex2:** left side's height = right side's height

```dart
body: Column(
  children: [
    Container(color: Colors.green, height: 40),
    Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          flex: 3,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: 50, // I want to dynamically adjust this height
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 7,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Column(
              children: [1, 2, 3]
                .map((e) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('testing - $e'),
                ))
                .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Container(color: Colors.grey, height: 50),
  ],
),
```

I tried **this solution** it's working, but I have to rebuild the page after the right side of the widget build. Otherwise, the blue color widget is not visible initially.

```dart
  final rightFlexibleKey = GlobalKey();

// Get the render box
  RenderBox? get rightBox => rightFlexibleKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;

// Calculate blue height
  double get blueHeight {
    if (rightBox != null) {
      return rightBox!.size.height - 20;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'll need `IntrinsicHeight`.

This widget helps its children adjusting their height dependently.
But keep in mind IntrinsicHeight is expensive widget.

```
Column(
      children: [
        Container(color: Colors.green, height: 40),
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 3,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Stack( // I don't know why you need Stack here. If you don't need, we can remove Column -> Flexible -> Stack 
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 7,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [1, 2, 3]
                        .map((e) => ListTile(
                      title: Text('testing - $e'),
                    ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(color: Colors.grey, height: 50),
      ],
    )
```